# CrawlerProcess / Doesnt bring any item / Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have made a very simple try based on scrapy documentation, to make spiders run from a single file with CrawlerProcess. Here is the code :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class BaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
def common_parse(self, response):
    yield {
        'test': response.css("title::text").extract()
           }


class MonoprixSpider(BaseSpider):
# Your first spider definition
name = "monoprix_bot"
start_url = ['https://www.monoprix.fr/courses-en-ligne']

def parse(self, response):
    self.common_parse(response)

class EbaySpider(BaseSpider):
# Your second spider definition
name = "ebay_bot"
start_url = ['https://www.ebay.fr/']

def parse(self, response):
    self.common_parse(response)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MonoprixSpider)
process.crawl(EbaySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

Both spiders open and close without yielding page title (as a test). I had previously more complex Ebay and Monoprix spiders into two different projects, and it worked fine...

Am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 1):

Please change **start_url** to **start_urls**.

As in

```
start_urls = ['https://www.monoprix.fr/courses-en-ligne']
```

As there is no start_urls, basically you are seeding spider as empty.